# I want User to be able to review courses

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart

I have a list of courses from my university that the students can review. How do i integrate in flutter so that user can search for a course and leave a review once with this info - term taken, professor, review under 20 words and rating 1-5.
Someone told me use firebase but I am not sure how to.
I have list of all the courses with no of credits and description in  a txt file.

Comment: at least try something yourself. If you are stuck on something specific, ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is general practical you need a server to connect human from distance.
Firebase is best option for the beginner. it is easy to implement with any plate form like flutter. Thanks